# Printing first letter of full name python

Tags: python, for-loop, input, methods, split

Hello I'm trying to create a program that takes input and prints out the initials all uppercase but I can't figure out why my program is only printing the first letter of the last item of the list after string is split

this is my code:

```
full_name = input("Please enter your full name: ")

name = full_name.split()

for item in name:
    new_name = item[0].upper()
    
print(new_name)
```

Comment: `new_name = item[0].upper()` assigns a new value to `new_name` each time the loop repeats. It does not accumulate the letters from each iteration. Since `print()` is outside the loop, it only prints the last value which was assigned to `new_name`.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. It has some great tips that would help you find this error in your code.

Comment: What is an example of your expected input?

Comment: Indent `print(new_name)` to move it inside the loop.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Have you heard of string concatenation? It may be useful here...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new, empty variable like `initials` and add the first letter to it

```py
full_name = input("full name: ")

name = full_name.split()

initials = ""

for item in name:
    initials += item[0].upper()

print(initials)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. But why did you create the empty string? what exactly does that do?

Comment: It is a placeholder to hold the characters that you extract from the full name.  The for loop appends it to that variable.  Without it, when you try to add the letter to the variable, you will get a `NameError: name 'initials' is not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

```
# get the full name from the user
full_name = input("Enter your full name: ")

# split the name into a list of words
name_list = full_name.split()

# loop through the list of words


for i in range(len(name_list)):
    # get the current word
    word = name_list[i]
    # uppercase the first letter of the word
    word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
    # replace the word in the list with the new word
    name_list[i] = word


# join the list of words into a string
full_name = " ".join(name_list)

# print the full name
print(full_name)
```